# Replacing int value with null

Tags: mysql

When I have an `int` column and most of the data is a number, but I have a few where there is no data and I am trying to fill it in with a `null`. how do you go about this? (In summary a `null` value in place of an `int`).

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeSalary
(EmployeeID int,
JobTitle varchar(50),
YearsOfService int,
Salary int
);


INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary VALUES
(101, 'Manager', 20, 80000),
(102, 'Desk Clerk', 5, 30000),
(103, 'Maintanence', 10, 60000),
(104, 'Sales', 'null', 'null'),
(105, 'Operations Manager', 'null', 'null')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes around `null` and put `NULL` in place of `'null'`...

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary (emp_id, emp_post, how_much_year, emp_salary) VALUES
       (1, 'Computer Engineer', 20, NULL),
       (2, 'Computer Scientist', NULL, 100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `'NULL'`, with single quotes around it, is a string literal.  You want to use `NULL`, without quotes:

```sql
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary (EmployeeID, JobTitle, YearsOfService, Salary)
VALUES
    (101, 'Manager', 20, 80000),
    (102, 'Desk Clerk', 5, 30000),
    (103, 'Maintanence', 10, 60000),
    (104, 'Sales', NULL, NULL),
    (105, 'Operations Manager', NULL, NULL);
```

Note that I also added the target colums of the insert, which is considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save text value in `YearOfService` column. Whenever you wrap any value in-between apostrophe i.e. `'` then it becomes a text value .

Use `null` instead of `'null'` it should work.

Valid insert query:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary VALUES
(101, 'Manager', 20, 80000),
(102, 'Desk Clerk', 5, 30000),
(103, 'Maintanence', 10, 60000),
(104, 'Sales', null, null),
(105, 'Operations Manager', null, null)
;
```

Please refer this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFRRf5r59J7UP2SFdch8ie/0)